# findString function returns wrong value

Tags: c, string

With the code below:

```
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <stdio.h>

/* 
 * ===  FUNCTION  =========================================================
 *         Name:  findString
 *  Description:  Determines if one character string exists inside other
 *                string. If found, returns location in source string. If
 *                not, returns -1.
 * ========================================================================
 */

int  findString ( const char  source[], const char  search[] )
{
    int  i, j;

    for ( i = 0; source[i] != '\0'; i++ )
        for ( j = 0; source[i + j] == search[j]; j++ ) 
            if ( search[j] == '\0' )
                return i;

    return -1;
}       /* -----  end of function findString  ----- */

/* 
 * ===  FUNCTION  =========================================================
 *         Name:  main
 *  Description:  Displays result of findString function.
 * ========================================================================
 */

int  main ( void )
{
    const char  source[] = "hello, world";
    const char  search[] = "lo, ";
    int  findString ( const char source[], const char search[] );

    printf ( "searching \"%s\" in \"%s\" returns %d.\n", 
            search, source, findString ( source, search ) );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}           /* ----------  end of function main  ---------- */
```

I expect the function findString function to return 3, but instead, it returns -1.  When running gdb, the source string prints "hello, world" and search prints "lo,".  But once I get in the findString function, the source string prints "lo, " and the search string prints "hello, world".  Why did they get switched?

Comment: Who puts a f. declaration in the main code(?)

Comment: It shouldn't because of the prototype inside main function, but since gcc supports nested function, it compiles there.

Comment: Whoops, forgot to recompile and link.

Comment: Yeah it only worked because I have gcc.  OP should take that out.  Shouldn't be there.

Comment: @vxs8122: how do you inspect the parameters? what gdb command do you run?

Comment: @BoltClock Why did you close this question. Your reasons are not acceptable. The problem is not a typo and includes a sscce and is reproducible. Please reopen.

Comment: @this: My reasons are not mine but the OP's. They flagged requesting that their question be closed. See their comment on Matt's answer.

Comment: Umm, okay you might want to explain that next time.

Comment: Ok, I was confused again.  The code probably did recompile and I did indeed get the error as Matt pointed out.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It fails because this test

```
source[i + j] == search[j]
```

is performed in the nested for loop before you get a chance to ask

```
if ( search[j] == '\0' )
```

Thus, in your example when `j` == 4 (and `search[j] == '\0'` is true), the first test will fail (because `source[i + j]` == 'w') and ultimately -1 will get returned.

Comment: @vxs8122 I don't know what you mean, it should return 3 as you said in your original post.

Comment: Sorry my bad.  I was confused at first because after recompiling I did indeed get 3, but just now I got -1.  I don't know what I just did before, but just recently fixed that and I got 3.